# BitmapSource.Create switches RGB values

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmapsource

I am loading pixels from a file onto an array of bytes using this code:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(filename);
var rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
int numBytes = bmpData.Stride * bmp.Height;
byte[] rgbValues = new byte[numBytes];
Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, numBytes);
```

I am pretty sure that this is not the problem.
After I have loaded the file, I want to display manipulate the colors and then display in a WPF window.

So I create a bitmap source with the following line:

```
BitmapSource img = BitmapSource.Create(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Rgb24, null, pixels, stride);
```

The problem is that the red bytes are switched with the green bytes.
It is similar to this - [Why color changes when save a BitmapSource to Bitmap for PixelFormat.Format48bppRgb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103852/why-color-changes-when-save-a-bitmapsource-to-bitmap-for-pixelformat-format48bpp) -
but i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Did you try `PixelFormats.Bgr24` instead of `PixelFormats.Rgb24`? And why all this `System.Drawing.Bitmap` stuff. That could certainly be done with pure WPF.

Comment: Well i'll be, it worked.  I thought I tried that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you may use `PixelFormats.Bgr24` instead of `PixelFormats.Rgb24` to create the BitmapSource.

```
var img = BitmapSource.Create(
    width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr24, null, pixels, stride);
```